# Is there a place to publish my stories to share it?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, self-publishing, version-control

First I did google for 4 hours before making this question but I did not found what I was looking for.

Secondly probably there is a question similar that I couldn't found.

I am programmer that usually makes code to share it on [github](http://github.com), a platform to store code.

Until now I was using it to store my stories and share it with friends and social media but I realized that sometimes I am missing like real feedback not biased by friendship.

I was wondering if there is a website like to post short stories for free and get other writers to read it and comment?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Remo Fiorentino*! You might be interested in the question [What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/904/what-are-good-places-to-post-your-work-where-it-will-be-read-by-others). If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: In fact that question solved my doubts. 
btw, thanks for the welcome! The tour really helped me out with some doubt about this website.

Comment: If the question I linked solved your problem I will go ahead and suggest that this is a duplicate so that future readers finding this question will be pointed towards the duplicate target. That makes it easier for them. This one will then be closed (if 4 other members with more than 500 reputation or you agree with the duplicate target) and can't receive any new answers. The goal of SE is to have canonical questions and answers. If you have some questions about how the site works feel free to ping someone by writing an "@" in front of their username (it autocompletes) and check out [meta].

Comment: @Secespitus While this question is the same as the one you point to, would the answers be the same in 2010 and now? The Internet is a fast-changing ocean.